# how to target a link with event.preventDefault?

Tags: jquery, hyperlink, target, preventdefault

i have a link with a click handler here. the href is filled with information i need. but i dont want the click to open this link. so i did event.preventDefault and it works fine. But i need to target="_top" ich someone clicks the link. is this even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

changed the `event.preventDefault();` function to `return false;` and did a html animatation with scrollTop: `$('html, body').animate({scrollTop:0});`

now the link is not following the href but it scrolls to top

Answer (score 0):

If you're preventing the default action of the link, I take it you're doing something else. If that something else involves changing the window location, and you want to change the location of the top window, you can use `window.top` to refer to it and then set its location via the `location` property, e.g.:

```
window.top.location = /* ... */;
```

For instance ([live example](http://jsbin.com/avufas)):

HTML:

```
<a id="theLink" href="http://jsbin.com">This link</a>
says jsbin.com and doesn't have <code>target="_top"</code>,
but will actually go to stackoverflow.com and do it
in the top window. (Seems a bit evil.)
```

JavaScript:

```
jQuery(function($) {

  $("#theLink").click(function(event) {
      window.top.location = "http://stackoverflow.com";
      return false;
  });

});
```

...but this raises the question of why not just let the link do its job. :-)

Or if you're trying to add `target="_top"` to a link that doesn't have it when it's clicked, you can do:

```
var link = /* ...get the link element, e.g., $("#theLink") or whatever */;
$("#theLink").click(function() {
    link.attr("target", "_top");
});
```

Note that I'm *not* preventing the default action there.

I wouldn't want to guarantee that would necessarily work, though — better to set the attribute before they click the link.